# How to delete data from file and move all info back

Tags: c, file, fopen

I created a file with `fopen` and I deleted the first value from the file and I want to take all of the values that are in the file and move them to the start of the file.

Example:

- File: `[Info,data,string]`
- Wanted: `[data,string,]`
- What is happening: `[,data,string]`

Any help will be great.

Comment: Copy all contents that you want to keep into a new file. Close the old original file. Rename the new file as the old file.

Comment: ..and with proper error checking, if anything goes wrong on the way (and it *will* during development), you still have the original file.

Comment: It looks like you're failing to delete the comma.  It's hard to give any detail since you provide no code.

Comment: _"I deleted the first value from the file"_: show us the code that does this. The problem is _there_.

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mre], and how to [edit] your questions to improve them.

Comment: There's a funny fprintf statement on line 42.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you have better to copy all data after the first byte into another file, then move that file into the original.  There's no system call to delete some part of the file, and close the hole around the deleted data.  The file internal structure is not suited to do that, and requires to copy/shift the whole file data to the proper place.